# MongoDB: Read Role Able to Write and Edit Collections

Tags: mongodb

I have created a user in MongoDB and it has read permission to a db, which i verified it by `db.getUser("username")`.

It confirms that it has read access.

However i am able to create and update collections in this db.
How is that possible?

Comment: Give me your user creation query.

Comment: db.createUser( { user: "skjdhf", pwd: "Iskjdfa" , roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "sakjdh" } ]} )

Comment: You gave the role readWrite, then obviously it'll insert data.Just use read alone.

Comment: @lakshayk, what is MongoDB version ?

Comment: Also make sure that you enabled authentication. `--auth true`

Answer (score 0):

> MongoDB: Read Role Able to Write and Edit Collections

As per `MongoDB BOL` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) **No**, Because **`read`** Provides the ability to read data on all non-system collections and on the following system collections: system.indexes, system.js, and system.namespaces collections. The role provides read access by granting the following actions:

1. collStats
2. dbHash
3. dbStats
4. find
5. killCursors
6. listIndexes
7. listCollections

> However i am able to create and update collections in this db. How is
>   that possible?

It possible through **`readWrite`** database user roles , It Provides all the privileges of the read role plus ability to modify data on all non-system collections and the system.js collection. The role provides the following actions on those collections:

1. collStats
2. convertToCapped
3. createCollection
4. dbHash
5. dbStats
6. dropCollection
7. createIndex
8. dropIndex
9. find
10. insert
11. killCursors
12. listIndexes
13. listCollections
14. remove
15. renameCollectionSameDB
16. update

For example here i am going to create new collection name with DBRole in test database and providing the role is readWrite.

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.createCollection("DBRole")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.DBRole.find()
> db.createUser(
...    {
...      user: "lakshayk",
...      pwd: "lakshayk123",
...      roles: [ "readWrite"]
...    }
... );
Successfully added user: { "user" : "lakshayk", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
```

And how to see the all users associated with that database.

```
> db.getUsers()
[
        {
                "_id" : "test.lakshayk",
                "user" : "lakshayk",
                "db" : "test",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "readWrite",
                                "db" : "test"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

Here again i am going to create new user with name of  "StackExchange" and also going to provide dbAdmin **Database Administration Roles** other than **Database User Role** client roles.

```
> db.createUser(
...    {
...      user: "StackExchange",
...      pwd: "StackExchange123",
...      roles: [ "readWrite","dbAdmin"]
...    }
... );
Successfully added user: { "user" : "StackExchange", "roles" : [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] }
```

And again I shall check all users from `db.getUsers()` to associated with that database.

```
> db.getUsers()
[
        {
                "_id" : "test.StackExchange",
                "user" : "StackExchange",
                "db" : "test",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "readWrite",
                                "db" : "test"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "dbAdmin",
                                "db" : "test"
                        }
                ]
        },
        {
                "_id" : "test.lakshayk",
                "user" : "lakshayk",
                "db" : "test",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "readWrite",
                                "db" : "test"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
>
```

I would like to say that here as i am able to see in your question statement, you are trying to fetch users through `db.getUser(username)` not with `db.getUsers()`.

As per W3resource documentation [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/shell-methods/user-management/db-getUser.php) `db.getUser()` method is used to return user information about the specified user from a database. The user must exist on the database on which the method runs.

**The Syntax is**

```
db.getUser(username)
```

And where [**`db.getUsers()`**](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/shell-methods/user-management/db-getUsers.php) The `db.getUsers()` method is used to return information for all users associated with a database.

**The Syntax is**

```
db.getUsers()
```

MongoDB grants access to data and commands through [role-based authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#roles) and provides built-in roles that provide the different levels of access commonly needed in a database system. You can additionally create [user-defined roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles).

For further your ref: [here](https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-users-and-permissions)